# How to remove gaps in navbar bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to remove some weird gaps in my navbar collapse elements.

The left hand side looks fine but the right is a mess (I want to add `ul` on the right hand side eventually).

Here is what it currently looks like:

[gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svkso.png)

Along with my current code:

```
<div class="pos-f-t">
      <div class="row">
  <div class="collapse col-md-6" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
      <h4 class="text-white">About</h4>
      <span class="text-muted">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, usu ea vide civibus. In sed purto delectus, ne has iuvaret postulant reprimique. Id equidem dolorem usu. Mea saepe possit integre at, vitae conceptam mea an. Nam fugit lucilius te, an mediocrem adversarium quo. Sea ea noluisse sapientem, et vix aliquam propriae philosophia, qui dicit antiopam cu.
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="collapse col-md-6" id="navbarToggleExternalContent2">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
      <h4 class="text-white">About</h4>
      <span class="text-muted">
        fooknkln;
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent,#navbarToggleExternalContent2" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I believe this is enough information to be minimally reproducible.

I honestly don't know how to fix this.

I have tried adding `fluid` but that didn't work.

I'm new to bootstrap so not very good!

Let me know if I need to do anything else as I am new to the site!

Comment: r u using bootstrap 4?

Comment: Yes, I believe so I have this script. `<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vcudq2z1/

The first thing to do is to remove unnecessary code or nesting, the other was to make the entire header dark and not just the `.collapse` selector.

UPDATE: https://jsfiddle.net/edonrexhepi/je76yhgs/

For some reason, the `collapse` class does not animate the padding.

Comment: Hi this does work in terms of visuals but now this animation is not smooth at all, can you help fix this?

Comment: @easyijoijo I've updated my answer, it seems that for some reason `padding` is not getting animated, that's why it is not smooth.